# Axios does not send appropriate error response [React]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to handle the error responses from Axios with React, but when i try to console log it the error is `Network error` and the `error.response` is undefined.

The request is a simple POST with the `Authorization` header correctly setted, when I try to do the same request on Postman it works correctly and I'am able to see the error response.

The request is made after the user fills a form and click on a button.

```
async function create() {
  const response = await Axios.post(
    "/api/disposal-requests/", // the base url is setted when the application mounts `Axios.defaults.baseURL = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL`
    {
      description: "Description",
      url: "Url",
      key: "Key",
      location_geoname_id: "City",
    }
  );

  return response.data;
}
```

When a user clicks on a button there is another function that calls the `create`.

```
async function onClick() {
  try {
    await create();
    // Everything works fine when there are no errors
  } catch(error) {
    // Here error.response is undefined
  }
}
```

This is what i receive in the console.log, in the `Network tab` I can see the error status is 400 but even there there is no error response, I'am able to see the error response only on Postman.

[image]

Does anyone know what's wrong here ?

Comment: `create()`  is an async function and you are not awaiting it,

Comment: I've edited the answer, because I wrote an example of the code, I'm awaiting it in the real code

Answer (score 0):

Please write await before creat(). so that if any any error occurs, catch with get that

```
async function onClick() {
    try {
      await create();
      // Everything works fine when there are no errors
    } catch (error) {
      // Here the error response is undefined
    }
  }
```

Comment: I've edited the answer, because I wrote an example of the code, I'm awaiting it in the real code

Comment: okay, did it work?

Comment: No, I meant I already await the function in the real code, so the problem is not that one